# Kubernetes deployment/service specification app vs run label

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to connect a k8s deployment to a (Oracle DB) deployment/service. Here is my DB deployment and service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: oracle-db
  labels:
    app: oracle-db
spec:
  ports:
  - name: oracle-db
    port: 1521
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 1521
  selector:
    app: oracle-db
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: oracle-db-depl
  labels:
    app: oracle-db
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: oracle-db
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: oracle-db
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: oracle-db
        image: oracledb:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1521
        env:
          ...
```

I'm wondering in the labels sections, what exactly is the difference between specifying 'run' vs 'app' (both of which I have seen used). I have scoured the k8s documentation and cannot find an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually the only difference between `run` and `app` is the name, labels are used to identify the object in Kubernetes and you can give the name that you like, not necessarily app or run.

You probably can find a lot of `run` online because if you create an object via imperative command the tag `run` will be placed automatically for you.

Of course you can change this to a key/value pair that makes more sense to you.

According to k8s [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/):

> Labels are intended to be used to specify identifying attributes of objects that are meaningful and relevant to users, but do not directly imply semantics to the core system.
>
> Labels can be used to organize and to select subsets of objects.
>
> Labels can be attached to objects at creation time and subsequently added and modified at any time. Each object can have a set of key/value labels defined.
>
> Each Key must be unique for a given object

Answer (score 6):

Labels are arbitrary key value pairs. There is no special meaning of `app` or `run`. You can choose any key and value for your labels. One thing to remember though is that the **service's selector needs to have a label which matches with what has been specified as label on the deployment otherwise it will not work**.

So if you have `app: oracle-db` label in your deployment then have `app: oracle-db` in service's selector and if you have `run: oracle-db` label in your deployment then have `run: oracle-db` in service's selector.